# Table from the mapped JSON object consisting of many arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm working on a project in React and I'm having trouble mapping the JSON object that gets from the API. I want to get a table like this:

[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l1D7xBsj51vJEDfVqRD0le9mg4VyMRXe/view?usp=sharing)

and the JSON object looks like this:

```
{
"userName": "user1",
"memberCommunity": [
    {
        "userName": "user5",
        "community": [
            {
                "level": 1,
                "members": 3
            },
            {
                "level": 2,
                "members": 3
            },
            {
                "level": 3,
                "members": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userName": "user18",
        "community": []
    },
    {
        "userName": "user2",
        "community": [
            {
                "level": 1,
                "members": 3
            },
            {
                "level": 2,
                "members": 4
            },
            {
                "level": 3,
                "members": 3
            },
            {
                "level": 4,
                "members": 6
            },
            {
                "level": 5,
                "members": 2
            },
            {
                "level": 6,
                "members": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The table image was created exactly on the data that I gave. The problem here is the proper use of the Map function, thanks to which I will get records with three users and for each of them the appropriate value in the level field. I hope I won't mix it up and you know what's going on :) Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with 2 `reduce` functions to iterate over the nested arrays.

```js
const data = {
  userName: "user1",
  memberCommunity: [
    {
      userName: "user5",
      community: [
        {
          level: 1,
          members: 3
        },
        {
          level: 2,
          members: 3
        },
        {
          level: 3,
          members: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      userName: "user18",
      community: []
    },
    {
      userName: "user2",
      community: [
        {
          level: 1,
          members: 3
        },
        {
          level: 2,
          members: 4
        },
        {
          level: 3,
          members: 3
        },
        {
          level: 4,
          members: 6
        },
        {
          level: 5,
          members: 2
        },
        {
          level: 6,
          members: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const format = data.memberCommunity.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [curr.userName]: curr.community.reduce((acc2, curr2) => {
      return {
        ...acc2,
        [`level ${curr2.level}`]: curr2.members
      }
    }, {}),
  };
}, {});

console.log(format);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! I would never have thought of it in my life :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: uhh, but I still have a problem mapping this objects to my table in React. Could you help me again? I think that if this object is an array of objects, then the map function can do it

Comment: It is a representation of a multi-dimensional array. You can use Object.keys(myObj) to get an array of all the users. `[user5, user18, user2]`. So you can use that to display your vertical axis.

I assume your levels will be static (1-6 or something) as your horizontal axis.

Then, you can access each variable with `myObj[currentUser][currentLevel]`

Comment: I want something like that:

  ...{
      userName: "user5":
      community: {
        level1: 3,
        level2: 3,
        level3: 1
      },
    ...
Generally, I want to replace arrays to objects, looking at the object to the beginning of the post. Can you help me last time? Pleace